# Entry within an entry

Tags: playa, structure

I'm creating a newspaper style website. The homepage is made up of 'editions', each date should have a homepage with all the articles selected for that edition. I figure the best way to do this is with Playa.

I have a channel for articles, videos and graphics (listings in structure).

I've also created a channel for the editions (which is a listing in Structure), and using Playa you can select which articles, videos and graphics should be selected for that edition.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="editions" dynamic="no" limit="1" show_future_entries="yes" start_on="{current_time format="%Y-%m-%d 00:00"}" stop_before="{current_time format="%Y-%m-%d 23:59"}"}

{home_main_article} (Playa field)
<h2>{title}</h2>
<div class="author">by {author} on {entry_date format="%d-%m-%Y"}</div>
<p>{article_content}</p>
{/home_main_article}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

My issue is this: Articles created on dates that don't match the date the edition was created, don't show up. Even with `show_future_entries="yes"` set, they still don't show. This may be because of the home channel is set to only show the edition for that day... Essentially articles, videos and graphics should be able to be created on any day and linked to any edition, that edition should show the entry content.

Comment: Did you test your theory by removing start_on="{current_time format="%Y-%m-%d 00:00"}" stop_before="{current_time format="%Y-%m-%d 23:59"}" from the channel tag?

Comment: If I remember correctly removing that still didn't show the entries. I had to add show_future_entries="yes" on the Playa field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

indeed the parts can be related with playa, the main edition could be fetched with year="" month="" and day="". you'ld need some logic with segment_n conditionals and preload_replace or switchee to check if the segments where filled in.

---

*Edit: examples added*

**Preload_replace**

You can use `{preload_replace:varname="value"}` to set a variable that is instantly replaced in the entire template. Because it is instantly replaced, a second preload replace will not find any variable `{varname}` left in the template. However, simple segment conditionals are parsed earlier so we can use that to our advantage.

Say you have year in segment_4 then you can check if segment_4 is empty and set a preload variable accordingly.

```
{if segment_4==''}
  {preload_replace:p_year="{current_time format='%Y'}"}
{/if}
{preload_replace:p_year="{segment_4}"}

# if segment_4 is empty then {p_year} will hold the current year,
# otherwise it will hold the value from segment_4
```

You can then set the channel:entries parameter year="{p_year}" and similar for month="" and day="".

**Switchee**

Another approach i have used somewhere, is using switchee on
`variable="{segment_4}/{segment_5}/{segment_6}`,
in combination with a crazy regular expression on the case value=""
to filter correct date ranges (only for year and month in this case).

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_3}/{segment_4}/{segment_5}" parse="inward"}
  {case value="#[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]/([0][1-9]&#124;[1][0-2])/#"}
    // show archive year="{segment_3}" month="{segment_4}"
  {/case}
  ... other cases
{/exp:switchee}
```

Comment: When I used year="" month="" and day="" on the main edition it didn't bring in the results from Playa. But, I've found that adding show_future_entries="yes" on the Playa field itself will work fine. Can you elaborate on preload_replace or switchee with an example? Many thanks.

Comment: added preload_replace and switchee examples.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="editions" dynamic="no" limit="1" show_future_entries="yes" url_title="{freebie_2}"}

   {home_articles show_future_entries="yes"}
     {title}
   {/home_articles}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The url structure is website.dev/edition/2013-04-01 (title of the edition)